# Convert svg to png with special characters

Tags: svg, png, converters, inkscape

I am using inkscape command line in windows to convert an svg to png with special characters as text in the svg.

For example < 10 is one of the items.

How can I escape the less than character in the svg when I convert it without returning something like & lt ; in the output/png?

Answer (score 0):

Once you open your svg file in inkscape, use the `File->export` and chose png as the extension. At least it works for me